# RS232 to UART using MAX232 and Arduino

Tags: arduino, serial-port, uart

I have a bar code reader/scanner with RS232 output. I have tried connecting to my PC using RS232 to USB cable ([shown in bottom right of the bar code scanner image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZnx1.jpg))

Then used Putty at COM11 and baud rate set to 9600bps.
I was able to scan bar codes with no errors.

The problem is when trying from RS232 to UART. i have used MAX232 and MAX3232 to be able to convert from RS232 to UART and read it using an arduino.

Using MAX3232 just gave no output at all (tried swapping TX and RX). Common ground is connected and tried connection and disconnecting VCC of the board and still no output

Using MAX232 did show some results in the arduino serial output when +5V is not connected and common ground is connected. ([results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n77S2.png))

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: used the following: http://www.mikroe.com/add-on-boards/communication/max232/

Comment: Best practice is to use an oscilloscope to determine TxD and RxD connections.  I've found the markings on some RS232 transceiver boards to be confusing.  Otherwise use the schematics to ensure that you always connect an output to an input, and never input to input nor output to output.

Comment: *"when +5V is not connected and common ground is connected."* -- You're wasting your time trying to use electronics without power.  Are you that clueless?